# C# Selenium Shorthand Code

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to create a method that allows you to type

```
ClickOn(YourVariable);
```

Instead of typing out

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(YourVariable)).Click();
```

I assume this would be an extension method, and I have a few like this:

```
public static IWebElement x(this IWebDriver driver, string xp)
{
    return driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xp));
}
```

This is the method I'm working on:

```
public static IWebDriver ClickOn(this IWebDriver driver, string button)
{
    return driver.FindElement(By.XPath(button)).Click();
}
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `Void` to `OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver`

I understand why I am receiving the error, but I can't think of any solution or workaround.

Any and all help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure this wil be your expexcted: driver.FindElement(By.XPath(button)).Click();  return driver;

Answer (score 2):

You can have your method like this :

```
public static IWebDriver ClickOn(this IWebDriver driver, string button)
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(button)).Click();
        return driver;// this driver will capture latest changes done
    }
```

I would prefer to have `IWebDriver` global instance(singleton) which can be used anywhere so that latest changes through out browser can be in that global singleton driver.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are trying to return a `.Click()`. `.Click()` doesn't have a return type (it's `void`). You don't need to return any type if all you want to do is click an element.

I would suggest that you pass in a `By` instead of a `string` so that you can use any locator type and not be locked into XPath (which I wouldn't recommend for general usage). The below should work for you.

```
public static void ClickOn(IWebDriver driver, By locator)
{
    driver.FindElement(locator).Click();
}
```

Comment: Hello Jeff, Thank you for your response. The IDE isn't showing me any errors with this code, so thank you. But oddly, I can't use it. Whenever I try to call it in the main line of code like this:

ClickOn(password_field);

I get the error saying "The name 'ClickOn' does not exist in the current context."

Would you know why this would be? The format is just like my other extension methods which are able to be used without error.

Comment: It will depend on where you put the `ClickOn()` code. Hover over the error and see if there are suggested fixes. That will help narrow down the fix.